# Xamarin Forms Android AppCompatActivity Toolbar background color is not changing

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-toolbar, android-theme, appcompatactivity

In my **Xamarin Forms Android** Project I need to change the **ToolBar** `Title color` and `background color` I have tried with many workarounds suggested in Google but unfortunately I am unable to find the correct solution to me

**What I Need is**

[image]

**What I am getting** Now is [image]

by using below **codes**

**MainActivity.cs**

```
[Activity(Label = "Sample.Droid", Icon = "@mipmap/icon_launcher", Theme = "@style/MyTheme")]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
            protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
            {
                base.OnCreate(bundle);

                global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);          

                LoadApplication(new App());
            }   


    }
```

**styles.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"> 

        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>     
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>    
        <item name="colorPrimary">#cc66ff</item>  
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>          
        <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>  

    </style>
```

**Toolbar.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#cc66ff"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

**What I have tried**

I have tried to change the `android:background` in `Toolbar.xaml` but it doesn't have any impact on it;it is always displaying Dark background in Toolbar

and also I tried with this below code too in **MainActivity.cs** this hides the title in the Toolbar

```
 var toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);             
              SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

anyone please guide me to resolve this issue and make me get what I need Thanks in advance

Comment: In your `OnCreate` method, where is `TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;` ?  Have you forgot that?

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT Thanks to remember, I have added `ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;` this line in `OnCreate()` then I am getting what I need except `Back button`. Tool bar `background color` and `title color`have changed but back button is still in black color.

Comment: Hi, still can't change the back button's color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you app class (PCL), add these to change the back button's color:

```
NavigationPage naviPage =  new NavigationPage( new App13.MainPage());
MainPage = naviPage;
naviPage.BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#cc66ff");
```

I have made a [demo](https://github.com/xiaolvzi/BackButton) for you.

### Update:

From [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/103317/change-navigation-bar-back-button-color-in-xamarin-android), like @MarlonRibeiro has said, you can use `drawerArrowStyle` to change the back button's color to white(I have updated my project on github):

```
 <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    </style>
<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="color">#FFFFFF</item> 
</style>
```

Comment: I have tried with your code but it is changing the `background color` of navigation bar, not the `back button`.

Comment: @is there a way to change the back button color to white?

Comment: It is white default, I think there should be a way change its color, I will try it and leave you a comment.

Comment: Hi, [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/103317/change-navigation-bar-back-button-color-in-xamarin-android), that works well. I have updated my github.

Comment: It is working good; I can change the back button color using  `<item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
<style name = "DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="color">#FFFFFF</item>
     </style>` below code